# Why does a window appear to select tables when I create a QueryTable with a connection from a odc file?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am connecting to SQL Server in excel using vba. I create a QueryTable object, and I pass the Path of the .odc as the Connection parameter.

The odc file looks like this:

```
<xml id=docprops></xml><xml id=msodc><odc:OfficeDataConnection
xmlns:odc="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:odc"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<odc:Connection odc:Type="OLEDB">
<odc:ConnectionString>Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User   ID=sa;Password=thepassword;Data Source=server\MAPS,1433;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=MYID;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=DIALIMENTOS</odc:ConnectionString>
<odc:CommandType>Table</odc:CommandType>
</odc:Connection>
</odc:OfficeDataConnection>
</xml>
```

The QueryTables work fine, but when I create them, a window appears asking me to select the tables for the connection. I do not need this as the querys are in the vba.

How can I prevent these windows from appearing when I create the QuerTables? Am I missing something in the odc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ODC file defines a connection to a server (the connection string) and specifies that the query will look for a table (via the command type).  However you don't specify the table name, so that is why Excel pops a window open and asks for one.

I have not tested this (I generally use ODC's to CALL stored procedures), but my guess to prevent this would be to specify a table in the ODC file.  The table you choose is irrelevant (although it should exist), because your VBA code should overwrite it, based on your question.

Try inserting the following line after the CommandType line:

```
<odc:CommandText>sometablename</odc:CommandText>
```

This should be enough to get Excel to stop pestering you.